# JavaScript event not being fired

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Once `#theButton` is clicked, an alert should be triggered. Why aren't any of the events being triggered using the following methods?

```
            var theButton = document.getElementById("theButton");
       
            theButton.onclick = function(){alert("Clicked!");}
            theButton.onclick = clickAlert;
            theButton.onclick(alert("Clicked!"));
    
            function clickAlert(){
                alert("Clicked!");
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" id="theButton">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Attention to detail is very important in programming, lack of attention to detail shows a certain lack of professionalism. Poor spelling and mis-spelling function names is indicative of a lack of attention to detail. Also your logic is flawed, you are assigning the same thing to onClick over and over, before the button actually exists.

Comment: Had you wrote that to begin with, I would have been fine because i would learn something from it.  But sarcasm doesn't teach anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three problems

1. You misspell `function` on line 7. (This generates a runtime error, by the way)
2. You try to access the node #theButton before it's available in the DOM.  Take Pekka's advice for this one
3. You overwrite the `onclick` property on line 8 - not sure if you're doing that on purpose or what

Answer (score 1):

Because `theButton` doesn't exist yet when you run your script?

Wrap it into the body's `onload` event or jQuery's `ready()`.

Comment: jQuery's `ready()` is a wrapper for `DOMContentLoaded` event, not `laod` event.

Comment: @Crozin I know, but IIRC, getting `DOMContentLoaded` without jQuery across browsers was awfully difficult. Still, you are right.

Comment: What do you mean by does not exist yet?

Comment: @Babiker at the point the Javascript is executed, the DOM isn't rendered by the browser yet, so you can't access any elements in the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping it in the document.Ready() function.

Comment: That doesn't necessarily exist - the OP is not using jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

I like the `jQuery.ready()` answer, but I believe you could also move the `<script>` block to some point afeter you delcalre the button like at the end of the page.

Comment: ... or use the `onload` event.

Answer (score 1):

It works if you put the onclick within the input tag (and spell things right):

```
<html>
     <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">



       function clickAlert(){
        alert("Clicked!");       

       }

      </script>
     </head>
     <body>
      <input type="button" id="theButton" NAME="theButton" onclick="clickAlert()">
     </body>
    </html>
```